# How to implement SSL connection between Device and server?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We have the MobileFirst platform running on our Linux machine. Business Logic Web services are running on a separate Server. The Certificate is issued by our Business Server.

We have overwritten the MobileFirst certificate mfp-default-cert.crt with the certificate issued by our Server. This certificate is used to establish the HTTPS SSL connection between the MobileFirst adapter and the web service.

We have successfully integrated this encrypted web service (using SSL) between MobileFirst (using HTTP Adapter) and Server in a Native app.

Now we want to implement/configure SSL connection between Mobile Device/emulator  and MobileFirst server for secure communication using the same issued certificate.

Can anyone please advise how to do that?

Comment: I don't understand the question here...

You say you have successfully done everything and it is working when the application is communicating to the backend via adapters with SSL.

Now you want to do the same with the Emulator/Simulator of the same app? What is his app? Android? iOS?

Regardless I do not see why this would be any factor in the communication.  
If you are getting *failures in the log* you need to provide those.

Answer (score 0):

As we know for SSL Connection, there should be a proper handshake to happen between the server and client.

Client(Device/Emulator) which you are trying to connect with server should have a corresponding CA Certificate installed on it so that it will have a successful secured communication with sever machine .

so you should have the client side certificate(example.crt) installed on your device/emulator to connect the server on HTTPS port.

And it depends even on the Device u are using to connect .
For iOS devices from 9.0. Apple mandates more secure way of connection

https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/09/07/preparing-ibm-mobilefirst-platform-server-app-transport-security-ios-9/

Hope this serves your purpose. :-)